# Formatting all Variables in data frame using R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm using following code to format the data

```
lbls <- sort(levels(mydata1$CIGEVER))
lbls <- (sub("^\\([0-9]+\\) +(.+$)", "\\1", lbls))
mydata1$CIGEVER<- as.numeric(sub("^\\(0*([0-9]+)\\).+$", "\\1", mydata1$CIGEVER))
```

I've 90 variables as of now. I've tried for loop to format all the variables by this code

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mydata1) ) 
{
    for (j in 1:ncol(mydata1))
    {
        mydata1[i,j]<- as.numeric(sub("^\\(0*([0-9]+)\\).+$", "\\1", mydata1[i,j])) 

    }       
}
```

But, its taking too much time. Can anyone help me to improve the efficiency.

Original Data looks like

```
Column Name
---------------

(1) Good
(2) Very Good
(3) Excellent
(4) Bad
```

And after applying the formatting

```
Column Name
-------------------
1
2
3
4
```

Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the formatting you provided is correct, you can probably use `lapply` to avoid the double for loop:

```
mydata1[] <- lapply(mydata1, function(x) as.numeric(sub("^\\(0*([0-9]+)\\).+$", "\\1", x)))
```

(not tested in absence of sample data)

Answer (score 1):

As sub applies to vectors you can do all the columns at once:

```
for (j in 1:ncol(mydata1))
     {
        mydata1[,j]<- as.numeric(sub("^\\(0*([0-9]+)\\).+$", "\\1", mydata1[,j])) 

     }       
}
```

There are even quicker methods using `apply` like functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
 library(qdap)
 sapply(lapply(dat, bracketXtract, "round"),as.numeric)
#      col1 col2
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    2    2
#[3,]    3    3
#[4,]    4    4
```